# Check if directory is owned by specific user

Tags: directory, filesystems, cmake, rights-management

Is it possible to check if a folder (and all subfolders) are owned by a specific user/rights?

As Example: Can I use cmake to check if `/var/www/**` is owned by `www-data` and has the permission to execute files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake does not have this functionality built-in, but you can use [a third party CMake module](https://github.com/sakra/FileInformation) to obtain file permission and owner information.